# Python syntax in Apache Airflow

Tags: python, airflow

I'm really new to Apache Airflow and am currently reviewing a Python script in GCP's qwiklabs. I noticed this syntax and I got a bit confused by it:

**`input_file = input_file = '/home/airflow/gcs/data/rose.txt'`**

in this chunk of code:

```py
WORDCOUNT_JAR = (
    'file:///usr/lib/hadoop-mapreduce/hadoop-mapreduce-examples.jar'
)

input_file = input_file = '/home/airflow/gcs/data/rose.txt'

wordcount_args = ['wordcount', input_file, output_file]
```

Why is it `input_file = input_file = file_path`? What does it mean?

Thanks xD

Comment: I think It's a typo by the author. This is no special syntax or behaviour. Perhaps it should be `output_file = input_file = ` but that's just guessing.

Comment: true... I think that would make so much more sense. Still it would be great to know whether we are missing something here otherwise.

Comment: There is nothing related to airflow. It's just coding error from the code author.

Comment: Thanks! That's clear now